# bootstrap accordion not working in checkout page of custom opencart theme

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, opencart2.x

i am developing opencart project in customized theme.
now problem is that in checkout page bootstrap accordion is not opening next panel onclick of continue button.
so please help me to find where is the error.

### code of checkout.tpl

```
    <div id="page">
      <div id="winkelmand" style="padding-top:50px;">
      <div id="winkelmand-content">
         <div id="winkelmand-producten" style="height:auto !important;padding:10px;">
            <ul class="breadcrumb">
               <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
               <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
               <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_option; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-checkout-option">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-payment-address">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-shipping-address">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-shipping-method">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-payment-method">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-checkout-confirm">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

i have pasted javascript code to jsfiddle but just display purpose. it will not work because data in accordion coming from database.

https://jsfiddle.net/dipeshsoni/96aLv9js/

Answer (score 1):

I run in to similar problem today, I use css to fix it.

`.collapse.in { display: block!important; } .collapse { display: none!important; }`

Hope this will help someone.